# understanding nested locks in java

Tags: java

i want to understand this:

```
String string;
public Test(String string){
     this.string = string;
     .....
}

public void foo(newObjectPerCall o) {
        synchronized (o) {
            //each thread can enter here because the object passed is always different
            ....
            synchronized (string) {
                // acquire this lock if the String is free.
            }
        }
    }

public synchronized void function() {

}

public static void main(){
    Test test = new Test("hello");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
         WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(test);
         workerThread.start(); 
   }
 }
```

thread class

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    private Test test;

    public WorkerThread(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            test.foo(new Object());
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            test.function();
        }
    }
}
```

my doubts are:

- *if one thread acquire the inner lock, other threads that acquired the outer lock, will remains inside the `foo` function?*
- *When on thread ,for some reasons, remains outside the `foo` function, can this one acquire the lock of test instance inside `function`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if one thread acquire the inner lock, other threads that acquired the outer lock, will remains inside the foo function?

Yes. They will block, waiting to acquire the monitor for `string`.

> When on thread ,for some reasons, remains outside the foo function, can this one acquire the lock of test instance inside function?

Yes, it's entirely independent of the other monitors. A `synchronized` instance method is just equivalent to one whose body is

```
synchronized (this) {
    ...
}
```

If no other thread already owns the monitor for `this`, the "new" thread can acquire it regardless of what other monitors are owned. But as all your worker threads are using the same instance of `Test`, only one of them will be able to be "in" `function()` at a time. That can be at the same time as another thread is executing `foo()` though.

Comment: one more thing, if thread1 aquire both inner and outer locks, a thread t2, as you said, can enter inside `function()`, is there any problem that string is defined inside object class constructor?

Comment: @OiRc: If the code compiles, then it's not using a *local* variable declared within the constructor. It would help if you could update your post to show a short but complete example which compiles - it will make it a lot easier to reason about than using pseudocode. I'd advise against locking against string references anyway though. It's too easy to end up with unintended aliasing due to string interning.

Comment: i made a mistake, while i was writing the question. see update.

Comment: ok thanks, so the syncronized outer lock of `foo()` , will not block the cycle of other threads which don't enter in `foo()`, before i wanted that you should tell me a clarification of that, as you already did.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I know only the answer only for the first question

```
 if one thread acquire the inner lock, other threads that acquired the outer lock, will remains inside the foo function?
```

Yes